# Can i use the perfmon metrics collector for four server at a same time

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Can i use the perfmon metrics collector for four server at a same time.
Server agents are running on all four servers.

I have 4 virtual servers created on single physical server. I want to listen CPU Usage, Network, Memory from all 4 servers in perfmon collector in Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Perfmon Metrics Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) to your Test Plan
2. Add a separate row for each host and each metrics you want to collect. Specify server IP address or hostname and the port where [Server Agent](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMonAgent/) is running as well.

   [image: PerfmonMultipleHosts]

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for more information on using PerfMon in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks for quick suggestion. I have tried the solution but it is not suitable in my case. I have 4 Virtual servers created on single physical server. I am trying to listen the CPU usage and memory and different other info from all 4 servers. But it only shows the info from single virtual server.

Comment: I executed the serverAgent on two different ports on different virtuals server.I am able to get other metrics like network , Memory. But when I add two cpu metrics for 2 different servers it only shows one.and other metrics are also not collected.